# Will the in-body AF of my d7500 work on an AF-P lens with broken AF?

Tags: autofocus, focus-motor, nikon-d7500, af-p

I just bought a AF-P DX NIKKOR 10-20mm f/4.5-5.6G VR lens and it has no AF. I bought it for 100€ and it’s literally like new, that’s the only reason I bought it.

AF is not a priority for me as I will mainly use it for night photography, but I was curious to know if the in-body AF of my Nikon D7500 would work on the AF-P lens.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Can Nikon AF-S or AF-P lenses with broken AF motors be autofocused with bodies that have a built-in motor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27291)